# graphql mutation argument name is [Object: null prototype]

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

I try to post mutations query throw my `nodejs` based `grapql` api.

My schema in the server side:

```
...
input PostPickProps {
  userId: String
  matchId: String
  predictionModelId: String
  modelVersionNumber: Int
  modelVariationIndex: Int
  pickEnd: String
}

type Mutation {
  postPick(props: PostPickProps): String
}
...
```

Query from the app:

```
export const postPick = async ({
  userId,
  matchId,
  predictionModelId,
  modelVersionNumber,
  modelVariationIndex,
  pickEnd
}) => {
  const res = await fetch(`
    mutation {
      postPick(props: {
        userId: "${userId}"
        matchId: "${matchId}"
        predictionModelId: "${predictionModelId}"
        modelVersionNumber: ${modelVersionNumber}
        modelVariationIndex: ${modelVariationIndex}
        pickEnd: "${pickEnd}"
      })
    }
  `)

  return res 
}
```

my resolver in the server side:

```
export const postPick = async ({ props }) => {
  const {
    pickEnd,
    matchId,
    userId,
    predictionModelId,
    modelVersionNumber,        
    modelVariationIndex,       
  } = props        

  console.log(props) // output [Object: null prototype] { userId: 'hack' ...}
  ...
```

console.log output is not as expected:

```
[Object: null prototype] {   
  userId: '5cb51b16e6161e6e5cb51b16',  
  matchId: '5cb51b16e6161e6e401262c2', 
 predictionModelId:'5ca0f4afb88b3a2e006faa0d',   ....
```

I suspect get props object as declared on my schema.